# passing a bool value to another function not working properly?

Tags: c++, boolean

Very new to C++, only been working with it for a few days. I'm trying to write a simple console calculator that requests the user input a Y or N to confirm that the  result printed was actually correct.

I've called to a function that requests the user input a char for Y/N, which then returns that as a bool value as either true or false depending on what was inputted. It then returns to main with that bool, which is then passed onto another function that prints text depending upon whether true or false was passed. However whenever I run the program, it always prints both statements for true and false. I'm sure I've broken some kind of rule when using bools or there's some sort of small error but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
bool getConfirmation()
{
    std::cout << "Is this result correct? Y/N: ";
    char confirm;
    std::cin >> confirm;
    if (confirm == 'Y', 'y') return true;
    if (confirm == 'N', 'n') return false;
    else return false;
}

void confirmResult(bool confirm)
{
    if (confirm == true)
        std::cout << "Result is correct.";
    if (confirm == false)
        std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";
    else
        std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please input the first integer: ";
    int x{ getInteger() };
    std::cout << "Please input the desired operation: ";
    char op{ getOperation() };
    std::cout << "Please input the second integer: ";
    int y{ getInteger() };
    int result{ calculateResult(x, op, y) };
    printResult(result);
    bool confirm{ getConfirmation() };
    confirmResult(confirm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `confirm == 'Y', 'y'` is equivalent to `'y'`. `'y'` is not zero, so it counts as a true value.

Comment: You're using `std::cin >>` for user input, which is a recipe for trouble. I'd recommend using `std::getline` only.

Comment: @melpomene while being correct, this doesn't explain OP's stated behavior (`it always prints both statements for true and false`)

Comment: So then, how would I convert the user's inputted Y/N into a true false value properly?

Comment: `if (confirm == false)
        std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";
    else
        std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";` is equivalent to `std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";`. Both branches of the conditional contain the same code, so there's no point testing a condition first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`confirm == 'Y', 'y'` doesn't do what you think it does - this is an *expression* involving the built-in *comma operator*, which always evaluates to `'y'`. The correct code is:

```
confirm == 'Y' || confirm == 'y'
```

---

You will always see both

- `std::cout << "Result is correct.";`
- `std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";`

being executed because your boolean logic is incorrect.

```
if (confirm == true)
    A
if (confirm == false)
    B
else
    C
```

If `confirm == true`, then both A and C will be executed, as the second `if` statement is not introduced by an `else`. Your logic should just be:

```
if (confirm == true)
    std::cout << "Result is correct.";
else
    std::cout << "Sorry, please try again.";
```

Comment: Doesn't explain OP's stated result of `it always prints both statements for true and false`

Comment: @SergeyA: fixed.

Comment: `X == true` better written as `X`.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. A couple questions though:

So the comma operator can't be used in the way I used it? I should use the || inside of conditionals?

Comment: @SergeyA And I'm also confused as to why my boolean logic was incorrect exactly. I can't have multiple "if" statements? Just one and an else statement?

Comment: @melpomene That's a matter of style. Even if it doesn't do anything that the compiler can enforce it can be argued that it communicates intention or expectation

Comment: @LRadico The comma operator throws away the result of its left operand and only returns the result of the right operand.

Comment: @LRadico Each `if` is independent. If you want to have three or more mutually exclusive conditional branches, it's written `if(...) { } else if(...) { } else { }`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In that case, why does getConfirmation() work since I didn't follow that logic? I wrote    if(...); if(...); else;    instead of if, else, if, else.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Never mind, I figured it out myself by thinking about it a little. getConfirmation() works because the statement is a return statement, as in the function ends right then and there. The rest of the code isn't even read. If it wasn't a return statement, the other if statement would be executed and things would go awry like they did elsewhere. The return statement saved me. I've fixed everything, thank you for your help.